# Strange Update clause error (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm experiencing a really strange error. I have a table with only two columns (User and pass , both with text type). 
The program asks first, what column I want to modify. With a radio button , I point which column I want to modify.

By pressing any radio button, two text boxes appear . You have to enter the password and the new data to modify it.

The problem is that when making the modification , if I want to change the user column , all is work well... But if I want to change a thing of the Password column , release "update error clause".

Honestly, I do not see any error in this code:

```
Protected Friend Sub modificarAcesso(ByVal column As String, ByVal dato As String)
    Dim cmd As String = "Update Login SET " & column & "=@dato"
    Try
        con.Open()
        comando = New OleDbCommand(cmd, con)
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dato", dato)
        comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
        comando.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Problemas en la consulta: " + ex.Message(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You will be updating the entire table, you have no where clause. What is the SQL of the command that is failing? What is the entire error you are receiving?

Comment: The program only said  "Error in the UPDATE statement "... the answer below fix everything!

Comment: But you are still going to change every row to the same value

Comment: I know what you think ... I do not put WHERE because I will use only a single user.

Comment: Don't forget that you should never store passwords in plain text in a database - encrypt it or all the woes in the world will be yours.

Comment: Dont worry about that David :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Password is a keyword, so you must put it in brackets.  You should do this anyway if a column name has a space in it, too:

```
Dim cmd As String = "Update Login SET [" & column & "] = @dato"
```